# How to stop Javascript Pop Up from moving to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that is clicked (see picture below and note where the scroll bar is positioned) for a div pop up to come up using Javascript.

See image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1O3Ee_1Z5cRTko0anExazBBQkU/preview

When I click the button it brings the pop up, up at the very TOP of the page.

See image : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1O3Ee_1Z5cRWjFPS0xEV0tTeFk/preview

I would like the pop up to come up centered, at exactly where the page is scrolled to when I click on the button.

This is my code. Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//open popup
$("#pop").click(function(){
  $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
  positionPopup();
});

//close popup
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
});
});

//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup(){
  if(!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible')){
    return;
  } 
  $("#overlay_form").css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
      position:'absolute'
  });
}

//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);
```

HTML:

```
              <a href="#" id="pop" ><li style="float:right; margin-left:5px; list-style-type:none; line-height:0px; padding-top:20px;"><i class="fa fa-share-square fa-lg"></i></li></a>
              <br />
<form id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
        <a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>

    <h2> Hello, World.</h2>
    Share buttons here :-)
</form>
```

Comment: look at position fixed

Comment: Stick a debug breakpoint just inside positionPopup, and step through to make sure it does what you expect. I'd guess your overlay_form may not yet have a width or height (or even be visible yet) at the point you call positionPopup.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're positioning the popup using JS instead of CSS?

You could simply set the modal to:

```
#overlay_form {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -00px;  /* 1/2 the height of the modal */
  margin-left: -00px; /* 1/2 the width of the modal */
}
```

This approach doesn't require invoking JS code for every resize. You can still hide/show the modal with your current approach.

P.S. remember to give your modal a width/height value for the above approach to work.

EDIT: Try putting the form in a wrapper and making that wrapper the popup element, rather than the form. Like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="pop-up">
    <form id="overlay_form">
        <a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>
        <h2> Hello, World.</h2>
        Share buttons here :-)
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pop-up {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;   /* set this to whatever you want */
  height: 150px;  /* set this to whatever you want */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;  /* 1/2 the height of the modal (150 / 2) */
  margin-left: -150px; /* 1/2 the width of the modal (300 / 2) */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pzw20t0/)